# What is the difference in these uses?

Tags: difference, relative-clauses

Is there any difference in these uses:

1. **I need a shampoo whose formula is effective in treating hair loss.**
2. **I need a shampoo that has an effective formula for treating hair loss.**
3. **I need a shampoo with the right formula for treating hair loss.**
4. **I need a shampoo which contains an effective formula for treating hair loss.**

Are all of these sentences  just different ways of saying the same thing? Are all of them right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are all correct, and they are pretty much different ways of saying the same thing.  The possible exception is question 3.  To have the meaning of the others, I would reword it so:

> I need a shampoo with an effective formula for treating hair loss.

But other than that, yes, they are various ways to express the same idea, and there are no grammatical errors.